# Bluetooth How to data send to multiple device in queue?

Tags: android, bluetooth, send

I created the list that have device detected, and I want to send data to each device; The process is :  one device sent data to first device and after disconnect first device and start to connect second device and sent the same data to second device and after disconnect this process until the last device in device list.

So does it possible to do that?